# Disabling a radio button using jquery

Tags: jquery, primefaces, radio-button

I know there are other questions surrounding this topic but none of the answers have worked for me. Maybe I missing something but I've exhausted all approaches. I need to disable the 'yes' radio button if this was checked already. I have logic that gets kicked off when the yes is checked. I don't want it to be fired off again. Below is my code. Hopefully a second set of eyes will help.

```
function startDetection(checkbox) {

 if(checkbox.value == "true") {
  //other logic here that works just fine.
 $j(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('wizard-form:sec:rememberMyDevice:0')).attr('disabled',              true);
```

I know the 'PrimeFaces.escapeClientId' is a bit odd but that seems to be the only working way I've been able to call UI elements. I've tried all the normal jQuery calls to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: What is console.log($j(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('wizard-form:sec:rememberMyDevice:0')))

Comment: Not sure where you got console.log but yes the PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('wizard-form:sec:rememberMyDevice:0') is essentially calling my selectItem inside my p:selectOneRadio. Ive used the same call to check if it is selected so I know it works.

Comment: I meant when you log the element in the console, what do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

To disable an element you should use:

```
$('#id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And to re-enable:

```
$('#id').attr('disabled', '');
```

Comment: I dont think it likes the ':'. Thinks it is a selector.

Comment: can you post your html source from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the brand new prop function:

```
$('#id').prop('disabled', true);
$('#id').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: I'm on an older version of jQuery. This wont work for me. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 0):

To disable:

```
$('#elementId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To re-enable it:

```
$('#elementId').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Tried $j('#wizard-form:sec:rememberMyDevice:0').attr('disabled', 'disabled'). Didnt work.

Comment: what about that J? between $ and ( ??

Comment: That is what I'm are using to define jquery statements. That has to be there.

Comment: Maybe the colons in the element id are causing you some problems, because that code should work.

Comment: what does PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('wizard-form:sec:rememberMyDevice:0') return??